# How might I filter out one half of a relationship set between values of two columns?

Tags: powerquery, m

I'm trying to isolate one half of the relationship set between two columns in a table. For instance, if I have a table like this:

[image]

It show a relationship set between A and B (or B and A) twice. Once for each direction of the relationship...first A to B and then B to A.

So how might I be able to identify and filter out the second half (direction) of the relationship set?

[image]

To achieve a result like this?

[image]

Is there a "simple" way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a more efficient way, but this should work:

1. Add a column which creates a sorted text value of the two columns, possibly separated by a character that won't appear in either column. You can do this by calling `List.Sort` on a list of the cell values, and then using `List.Accumulate` to join the strings. For example, the expression to use in Add Custom Column could be `each List.Accumulate(List.Sort({[Column1], [Column2]}), "", (state, current) => state & ";" & current)`.
2. Use Remove Duplicates on the new column to get rid of the duplicate relationships (i.e. use `Table.Distinct`).
3. Remove the added column.

Comment: Thank you! I was getting nowhere with this before. Your solution works great!